# Create folder and Upload file to Google Drive from TypeScript cannot compile

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a folder in Google Drive from node.js, I found [an example here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder#creating_a_folder) that also shows how to upload a file into the new folder.

I use TypeScript and my code looks like this:

```
getAuthorizedClient().then((client) => {
  const drive = new drive_v3.Drive({ auth: client });
  const folderMetadata = {
    'name': `Order_${order.key}`,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
  };

  drive.files.create({
    resource: folderMetadata,
    fields: 'id'
  })
  .then((folder) => {
    console.log('Created folder Id: ', folder.id);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
})
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

When building the code, I get the following error:

```
src/assets-handler.ts:110:5 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ resource: { 'name': string; 'mimeType': string; }; fields: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'resource' does not exist in type 'BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>'.
```

Comment: I don't know enough about google-drive to really supply an answer, but realize that all errors in TypeScript are usually warnings.   Despite the error, it probably did compile, and may run.

Comment: It looks like a big in the type definition. Did you check the source?

Comment: What are the properties of BodyResponseCallback? Can you console.log for the values? On a successful call to [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) the available properties are found [here - file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource). However you are using a 'property' which does not exist in the file resource list. Try console logging the variables you are using to check for values.

Answer (score 1):

I looked up the type definition, and the `create` method(s) looks as follows:

```
create(params?: Params$Resource$Files$Create, options?: MethodOptions): AxiosPromise<Schema$File>;
create(params: Params$Resource$Files$Create, options: MethodOptions | BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>, callback: BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>): void;
create(params: Params$Resource$Files$Create, callback: BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>): void;
create(callback: BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>): void;
```

Looking then at `Params$Resource$Files$Create` it gives me this:

```
interface Params$Resource$Files$Create {
    /**
     * Auth client or API Key for the request
     */
    auth?: string | OAuth2Client | JWT | Compute | UserRefreshClient;
    /**
     * Whether to ignore the domain's default visibility settings for the
     * created file. Domain administrators can choose to make all uploaded files
     * visible to the domain by default; this parameter bypasses that behavior
     * for the request. Permissions are still inherited from parent folders.
     */
    ignoreDefaultVisibility?: boolean;
    /**
     * Whether to set the 'keepForever' field in the new head revision. This is
     * only applicable to files with binary content in Drive.
     */
    keepRevisionForever?: boolean;
    /**
     * A language hint for OCR processing during image import (ISO 639-1 code).
     */
    ocrLanguage?: string;
    /**
     * Whether the requesting application supports Team Drives.
     */
    supportsTeamDrives?: boolean;
    /**
     * Whether to use the uploaded content as indexable text.
     */
    useContentAsIndexableText?: boolean;
    /**
     * Request body metadata
     */
    requestBody?: Schema$File;
    /**
     * Media metadata
     */
    media?: {
        /**
         * Media mime-type
         */
        mediaType?: string;
        /**
         * Media body contents
         */
        body?: any;
    };
}
```

So no, the `resource` property does not exist, it is `requestBody?: Schema$File` instead.

But, when I changed my code to that it still gives me roughly the same error:

`src/assets-handler.ts:110:5 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ requestBody: any; fields: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'requestBody' does not exist in type 'BodyResponseCallback<Schema$File>'.`

It seems like I am hitting the wrong overload of the `create` method. So I added an empty object argument:

```
drive.files.create({
    requestBody: folderMetadata
}, {})
.then((res) => {
    console.log('Created folder Id: ', res.data.id);
})
.catch(err => console.error(err))
```